# How do you control text formatting when launching GAP scripts from the command line?

Tags: gap-system

I would like to understand GAP's behaviour when I launch a script from the command line, for example

```
$ gap mytest.gap
```

as opposed to calling it from inside GAP

```gap
gap> Read("mytest.gap");
```

In particular, I've tried to [suppress automatic formatting](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap10.html#X8663FCD57E8BC390) with line breaks and indentation. If the file `mytest.gap` is the following

```gap
SetPrintFormattingStatus( "*stdout*", false );
Print( Primes{[1..30]}, "\n" );
```

then I get the expected behaviour when calling it with `Read()`, namely

```gap
[ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113 ]
```

whereas launching it from the command line, I still get

```gap
[ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71,
  73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113 ]
```

Can somebody please give an explanation for this behaviour? Is GAP's treatment of scripts launched from a command line invocation documented somewhere? I couldn't find it in the manual, but the man page does say `usage: gap [OPTIONS] [FILES]` with documentation only of how the options are treated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that it is currently not possible to completely disable the output formatting of `Print` the way you tried.

However, you can work around the problem by using the newer stream APIs and `PrintTo`, like this:

```gap
s:=OutputTextUser();
SetPrintFormattingStatus( s, false );
PrintTo( s, Primes{[1..30]}, "\n" );
```

I logged this as a [bug in the GAP issue tracker](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/issues/1308), and perhaps we can fix it in the next release (or perhaps somebody will explain why it's "not a bug but a feature" ;-).